# get separate image of each detected letter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, text-recognition

I have written this matlab code (given below) for detecting text from an image. This code is detecting the text from the image, but now I want to create an output image for each detected letter from the image. Please tell how can I do that?

**Code:**

```
i = imread('text.png');
i1 = i;
imshow(i1);

i2 = edge(i1,'canny',0.3);
imshow(i2);

se = strel('square',2);
i3 = imdilate(i2,se);
imshow(i3);

i4 = imfill(i3,'holes');
imshow(i4);

[Ilabel num] = bwlabel(i4);
disp(num);
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel);
Ibox = [Iprops.BoundingBox];
Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4 92]);
imshow(i);

hold on;
for cnt = 1:92
    rectangle('position',Ibox(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r');
end
```

Comment: It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the `'Image'` property of [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html):

```
Ipops = regionprops(Ilabel, 'Image');
```

---

PS,
when calling `regionprops` it is better to explicitly define the requested properties, otherwise you waste resources computing all properties - includeing those you don't even need.
For instance, your code should look like

```
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel, 'BoundingBox');
Ibox = vertcat(Iprops.BoundingBox);  % no need for "reshape" here...
```